# Setting the intents for a navigation bar one layout will not let me create a click method for it, yet is same as other layout click intents

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin

The error I am getting is :

```
dashboard.cs(54,48): error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type `Android.Widget.LinearLayout' to `Dribl.Droid.Linearlayout'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
    dashboard.cs(55,17): error CS0019: Operator `+=' cannot be applied to operands of type `int' and `method group'
```

the code for the intents is

```
//actionbar layout btns
            surveysBtn = (Android.Widget.LinearLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.SurveyLayout);
            surveysBtn.Click += surveyBtn_Click;

            inboxBtn = (Android.Widget.LinearLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.InboxLayout);
            inboxBtn.Click += InboxBtn_Click;


            availabilityBtn = (Android.Widget.LinearLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.availabilityLayout);
            availabilityBtn.Click += availabilityBtn_Click;

            dashboardBtn = (Android.Widget.LinearLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.dashboardLayout);
            dashboardBtn.Click += dashboardBtn_Click;


void surveyBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Surveys));
            this.StartActivity(intent);
            this.Finish();
        }

        void dashboardBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(dashboard));
            this.StartActivity(intent);
            this.Finish();
        }

        void availabilityBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Availability));
            this.StartActivity(intent);
            this.Finish();
        }

        void InboxBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MsgInbox));
            this.StartActivity(intent);
            this.Finish();
        }
```

So on each page I recieve the error for the dashboardBtn and dashboardBtn.Click. every other btn i made above it is the exact same and works perfectly fine? What would be causing this ?

this is the navigation bar that the linear layouts are from that the user will click to navigate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:weightSum="100">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/dashboardLayout"
        android:background="@drawable/selector"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_dial_pad"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_weight="70"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Dashboard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/InboxLayout"
        android:background="@drawable/selector"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_weight="70"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Inbox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/SurveyLayout"
        android:background="@drawable/selector"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_alert"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="70"
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Surveys"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/availabilityLayout"
        android:background="@drawable/selector"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_group"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_weight="70"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Availability"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even with missing code the error is clear enough to see what happens. The button has been declared as `Dribl.Droid.Linearlayout` in your code what I assume is a class you have created on your project, some form of custom control, and you're retrieving it as an `Android.Widget.LinearLayout`.

If the declaration is correct then you can retrieve it as the correct class:

```
dashboardBtn = (Dribl.Droid.Linearlayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.dashboardLayout);
```

Once this is understood the second error is also clear, you have declared a function named `Click` on your `Dribl.Droid.Linearlayout` class hidding the Click event, rename that function to something that does not collide and it will be ok.

Comment: i fixed the first one with what you just said, but im not sure I understand what you mean by the second error..?

Comment: What you don't understand? You have a function named `Click` in the `Dribl.Droid.Linearlayout` class code. Rename that function as it has the same name as the `Click` event and hides it...

Comment: The other layouts that I made the click functions for are all the same and work. I didnt do this layout any different. all there is is the layout im using as a button for user to click and the page it is on. I havent made any Click function?

Comment: Post the code of your `Dribl.Droid.Linearlayout` class.

Comment: all layouts im making click methods for are in a nav bar xml layout, custom view for each corresponding view to display nav bar on each page

Comment: That's not a layout it's a class which inherlits from LinearLayout.

Comment: I have very very basic knowledge of any of this, you have completely lost me ... lol ... I literally just have layouts and cs classes for each layout. the nav bar is just an xml layout and on each views cs file it is in using setcustomview.. etc.

Comment: turned out all it came down to was a small case L in the code rather than a capital.... -.-